# How to get the relative node distance from a node to another?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a big block with several small blocks, which is outside but adhere to the big one, as my picture showed below. I have no idea how to set "node distance" relatively based on big block's width and height. please help on that.

my output:

[image]

my expectation: I would like the two blocks in same horizon level, and the small one will adhere to big one.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=0.9]{Verdana}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\tikzstyle{big} = [rectangle,draw,fill=blue!20,text width = 5em,text centered,minimum width=6em,minimum height=8em]
\tikzstyle{small} = [rectangle,draw,fill=green!40,text width=0.8em, text centered,minimum height = 1em]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [big] (in1) {1st instance};
  \node [small, above right of=in1] (port1) {1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\node [small, anchor=north west, at=(in1.north east)] (port1) {1};`

Comment: It looks not what I want, I want the small box OUTSIDE of big box. but this anchor still keep the small boxes inside.

Comment: The box is outside for me. Are you sure you did use "west" in the anchor and "east" in the at?

Comment: What a amazing trick... I did use both as east. Now it works perfectly for me.

Comment: BTW - I also tried \matrix{} and it also works for me, and it can adjust column sep. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `\node [small, anchor=north west, at=(in1.north east)] (port1) {1};`